# How to change default view for controller in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I was wondering can I change default view folder for a controller in Yii2?

If we can change layout just by using `public $layout`, how we can do it with view?

```
Class HomeController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public $layout = 'mylayout';
    public $view = 'newview';

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To achieve that your controller should implement [ViewContextInterface](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-viewcontextinterface.html).

```
use yii\base\ViewContextInterface;
use yii\web\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller implements ViewContextInterface
```

Then just add [getViewPath()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-viewcontextinterface.html#getViewPath%28%29-detail) method which should return the desired directory path:

```
public function getViewPath()
{
    return Yii::getAlias('@frontend/views/newview');
}
```

You can use aliases here.

Also check the official [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#organizing-views) about organizing views.

Comment: Thank you. `yii\base\Controller` already implements the interface, so the `implements ViewContextInterface` is redundant here.

Answer (score 2):

Since 2.0.7 you can simply write in your controller's init() method: `$this->viewPath = '@app/yourViewPath'`

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Yii 2.0.42.1, And added this in my controller.

```
public function init()
{
     $this->viewPath = '@app/modules/report/views/test';

      parent::init();
}
```