# How to custom render function of Yii2 framework

Tags: php, yii2

I want to change views folder of yii2 to structure bellow

```
 views
----default
    ----site
        ----index.php
        ----error.php
        ----login.php
```

In the siteController i'm using code bellow

```
public function actionIndex(){
    return $this->render('default/index');
}
```

and error

```
The view file does not exist: D:\wamp\www\yii2\backend\views\site\default/index.php
```

Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change default view for controller in Yii2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698934/how-to-change-default-view-for-controller-in-yii2)

Answer (score 1):

With your current code, the *Site Controller* search the view file under his view's folder `/views/site`, you need to get the right path:

```
$this->render('../default/site/index');
```

I suggest to create an alias for be more flexible, like *@default_views* in your main-local file:

```
'aliases' => [
        '@default_views' => '../default/',
```

So, the function:

```
public function actionIndex(){
    return $this->render(Yii::getAlias('@default_views') . 'site/index');
}
```

Comment: Or simply `$this->render('/default/site/index');`... Or better : set `viewPath` for the controller.